# SSIS 2008 failure when executing DTS 2000 packages through sql agent

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Any idea what happens in my case ? I developped a SSIS package with BIDS 2008 , it includes a Execute DTS 2000 package. In localhost I have no problem to run the package but as soon as i try the same from the server using the sql agent, the following error is thrown:
stackoverflow System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040427): Execution was canceled by user.

I guess compatibility files between DTS 2000 and SSIS 2008 are missing on the server, am I right ?
Database server used with the agent is SQL Server 2008 R2..

Thank you for you help
cheers

Comment: To recap the situation: a 2008 package calls a legacy dts package. Runs fine from BIDS. Fails to run from a 2000 agent.  How does the agent call it? OS command to dtexec? Does that box have ssis installed?

Comment: Actually I installed now slq server 2008 R2 and I still have now way to execute a DTS package  . I got the same message

Answer (score 1):

probably. SQL Server 2008 does not install run-time support for DTS packages. You have to install this run-time support yourself.

Link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143755.aspx)

Comment: sorry I forgot to mentionned Database server used with the agent is SQL Server 2000..

Comment: so you are using SQL Server 2000 to run a dtsx package that has a "Execute DTS 2000 package" task that runs a DTS package?

Comment: yes I'm using SQL Server 2000 to run a dtsx package that has a "Execute DTS 2000 package" task that runs a DTS package